# Piping svn diff produces ESC characters (OS X 10.7.5)

Tags: macos, bash, svn

Why is it that when I pipe `svn diff` output to, say `less`, I get a bunch of `ESC` characters?

```
$ svn diff | less

Index: test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb
===================================================================
ESC[1;31m--- test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb   (revision 0)ESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+++ test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb   (revision 66)ESC[0;0m
ESC[1;35m@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@ESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+require 'test_helper'ESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+ESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+class TourGuideTipTest < ActiveSupport::TestCaseESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+  # test "the truth" doESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+  #   assert trueESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+  # endESC[0;0m
ESC[1;34m+endESC[0;0m
```

However, if I direct output to a file (`svn diff > whatever.diff`) and then `less whatever.diff` it looks fine?

```
$ svn diff > whatever.diff
$ less whatever.diff

Index: test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb
===================================================================
--- test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb    (revision 0)
+++ test/unit/tour_guide_tip_test.rb    (revision 66)
@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@
+require 'test_helper'
+
+class TourGuideTipTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
+  # test "the truth" do
+  #   assert true
+  # end
+end
```

Comment: @Tim: Good point. @André: Please try to use `less -R` if this is available on OSX. This does pass the "raw control characters" to the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These escape characters mark parts of the output that are colored if they are not piped.

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/can-less-retain-colored-output) very similar question and its answer I suggest you try to use `less -R` instead of plain `less`.

If you want to use other tools than just `less`, you could strip the sequences with `sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9]*m//g'` as discussed in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream) answer.

Your complete command would then be

```
svn diff | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9]*m//g' | othertool
```

In OS X escape codes are different so the pattern must be changed. It also [seems](https://github.com/sampson-chen/sack/pull/3#issuecomment-14676822) to be the case that (using OS X) the escape sequence `\x1b` will work with `perl` but not with `sed`. A resulting expression that works for both linux and OS X is then:

```
svn diff | perl -pe "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]//g" | othertool
```

Comment: That's great. What if I wanted to use another program that doesn't have an option like `less -R`, such as [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (`svn diff | subl`)? Is there a way to tell `svn diff` itself to strip colors?

Comment: @AndréDion I updated the answer.

Comment: OS X does indeed include `sed`. Unfortunately this didn't seem to work—I still have escape characters. If you notice, the escape sequence in the snippet I pasted includes a `;` where in [the thread you linked to](http://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream) there are no semi-colons. I think the regex simply needs to be updated to account for it. The escape character is also different.

Comment: @AndréDion Okay, when I tested it on my linux system it worked. But from your question it seems that the codes are different on OSX. This means the `sed` pattern must be changed. Try `sed 's/\x1b\[[01];[0-9]*m//g'`.

Comment: @AndréDion I added two solutions that I googled. Please report if they work, because I cannot test them.

Comment: `perl -pe "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]//g"` did the trick! Thanks for all your help, Tim.

Comment: Since it's unlikely I'll commit that pattern to memory, I've created a convenient alias (`alias killesc='perl -pe "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]//g"'`) to use, e.g., `svn di | killesc | subl &`