# Removing ANSI Color Codes from a text file in VI

Tags: vim, colors

Using VI/Vim how can I remove color coding?
I found this: [Removing ANSI Color Codes from a Stream](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream/1445752?noredirect=1#comment2181406_1445752)

answer from @adam-katz @olibre

```
cat colored.logs | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

I thought I could translate this to command line in vim, but it fails with
no match found

```
>vim colored.logs
: s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g
```

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 9):

The `\x1b` escape sequence (which works in `sed`, also C source code and shells like `bash`) corresponds to an ESC (like the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.)

See the manpage for [ascii(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html):

```
Oct   Dec  Hex  Char
------------------------------
033   27   1B   ESC (escape)
```

The C-style `\xNN` sequence recognized by `sed` takes the hexadecimal representation of the character, which in the case of ESC is `1B`, so that's where `\x1b` comes from.

Vim doesn't recognize `\xNN` C-style sequences, but it actually does recognize similar sequences with a slightly different syntax: [`\%xNN`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25x), so one way you can translate that ESC sequence to `\%x1b`. The following works on Vim:

```
:s/\%x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g
```

But you can simplify it. Since ESC is a somewhat frequently used symbol, there is a special shortcut escape sequence for it: [`\e`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Ce). So this will also work:

```
:s/\e\[[0-9;]*m//g
```

Finally, as you noticed, it's possible to insert a *literal* ESC character in your match.

In Vim, it's usually possible to insert a literal character by preceding it with the [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V) combination.

So using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd> is one way to enter this sequence. It will be displayed as `^[`, but usually in a different color, to indicate it's representing a single character. Also, when moving the cursor around, it will only stop on top of the `^` and not the `[`, to be consistent with that being a single character.

You might have noticed that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> after the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is also possible, that's because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> is *the same* as <kbd>ESC</kbd>. In fact wherever you press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key (such as to exit insert mode), you could equivalently press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> instead, that would work. So much so, that the character produced by a literal ESC, `^[`, is actually a representation of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (the `^` symbol is often used for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, for instance try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in insert mode to see a `^A` for a literal `Ctrl-A` character.)

In general, using the backslash sequences (such as `\e` or slightly inferior `\%x1b`) should be better, since it's easier to store those in text files (such as your `.vimrc`), rather than literal special characters such as the literal ESC.

Answer (score 2):

from [search-and-replace-control-characters vi](http://[(No%20Title)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217010/search-and-replace-control-characters-m-i-in-vi))
I found that I can use CTRL-V followed by CTRL-[ to substitute for

```
\x1b
```

which leads to :

```
: %s/^[\[[0-9;]*m//gc
```

this successfully strips  ^[[35m, ^[[39m, ^[[37m ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a similar problem where `terraform show` was including ANSI color codes and when it came to redirecting the output into vim it would be completely messed up (e.g. it had a bunch of `^[[0m` and `^[[1m`).

My solution was to use the trick mentioned by @mancocapac (i.e. `Ctrl+v` then `Ctrl+[` to create the initial `^[` followed by a pattern that would cause all variations of the ANSI codes to be matched).

I had originally tried using just a single substitution command, which would match the given pattern but when entering `/` to start the replacement portion (e.g. `:%s/^[[.m/<replacement>/g`) the operation would fail to match the pattern and so nothing would be replaced.

I worked around this by first searching the pattern by itself, *then* doing a substitution but leaving the pattern section blank (as vim will use the last matched pattern automagically)...

1. `/^[[.m`
2. `:%s///g`

This worked for me.