# Strange characters in a file generated by `tree`

Tags: macos, command-line, tree

Why does the file output of the `tree` program include strange characters? Example:

```
$ tree -fFN --charset=utf8 -o list.txt test/
```

Contents of the `list.txt` file:

```
<0x1b>[01;34mtest<0x1b>[00m
├── <0x1b>[01;34mtest/folder-01<0x1b>[00m/
│   ├── test/folder-01/file-01
│   └── test/folder-01/file-02
├── <0x1b>[01;34mtest/folder-02<0x1b>[00m/
│   ├── test/folder-02/file-03
│   └── <0x1b>[01;34mtest/folder-02/folder-04<0x1b>[00m/
│       └── test/folder-02/folder-04/file-05
└── <0x1b>[01;34mtest/folder-03<0x1b>[00m/
    └── test/folder-03/file-04
```

What are these characters?

```
<0x1b>
[01;34m
[00m
```

I am using the Terminal app on macOS Mojave. Until a few days ago the output was correct without these additional characters.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suspect the "contents of the `list.txt` file" you posted is an *interpretation* (representation) of the actual content, not the literal content. Then it makes sense.

`<0x1b>` is what the program you used to view the file prints to represent the (unprintable) [ASCII escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) (in various circumstances the character may be referred to as `ESC`, `\x1b`, `\033`, `\e`, `^[`).

Then `<0x1b>[01;34m` and similar sequences are [CSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences). Your file contains SCI sequences that change color of the following text. Run `cat list.txt` to pass the file to the terminal as-is. If your terminal supports CSI sequences (it probably does) then you will see colorized text.

The sequences are there in the file because your `tree` put them there. In my Kubuntu `man 1 tree` states few options to colorize (or not) the output: `-C`, `-n`. Without any of these options the behavior depends on `LS_COLORS` and `TREE_COLORS` environment variables and on stdout being a terminal or not.

By default, if `LS_COLORS` (or `TREE_COLORS`) is set, `tree` will colorize its output to a terminal, but not if piped to a non-terminal (e.g. to a file or the next command in a pipeline). The quirk is if you tell it to write to a file with `-o` then its behavior *still depends* on whether stdout is a terminal or not. If you *redirected* stdout to a non-terminal

```
tree -fFN --charset=utf8 -o list.txt test/ >/dev/null
# or simply
tree -fFN --charset=utf8 test/ >list.txt
```

then the output would not contain color codes.

---

> Until a few days ago the output was correct without these additional characters.

Maybe there was no `LS_COLORS` in your environment until few days ago; and the files created earlier don't contain color codes. Did you add `LS_COLORS` to the environment recently? Or maybe the earlier files contain(ed) color codes but you used to examine them in a way that actually uses CSI sequences to display colors? or ignores them?

It's not clear if you want the color codes to be in the file in the first place.

Anyway check the manual of your `tree`. Use a proper option to force coloring or not-coloring, or manipulate the environment and/or redirections to make `tree` behave as you expect.

If you need to remove color codes from already existing files then pass each file through one of the filters from this post: [Removing ANSI color codes from text stream](https://superuser.com/q/380772/432690).

Answer (score 1):

I added the -n option and the problem was solved. I had added LS_COLOR to the .bash_profile file.

Comment: For the record: in general it's fine to [answer one's own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). Here, however, the explicit questions in the question body are "why does the output include strange characters?" and "what are these characters?". If your intent was to answer, then you should have answered the questions *you* formulated. If your intent was to give feedback to my answer, then you should have written a comment. Your answer may be not as detailed as my answer and you may even prefer accepting your own answer; but let it be an actual answer. I'm on the verge of downvoting.