# How to read Linux text files in Windows system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, encoding, character-encoding

For example, I run the `top` command and store it to a file in Linux, after that I open that file in Windows it contains some gibberish. Here is the file viewed in Notepad++:

[image: File contents]

The option to convert to UTF-8 in Notepad++ doesn't work.

How can I read that file in Windows? I tried using `dos2unix` but it doesn't work and gives the error:

> dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1B found at line 1

Edit: Trying the `sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g' file.txt` command gives the expected output but only in the terminal

Comment: The right way is to tell tools like `top` not to print these characters in the first place. Some tools modify their behavior automatically if their stdout is not a terminal. It seems `top` does not do this. Use `-b`, e.g. `top -b -n 1 >output`; see `man 1 top`. In general, if some `troublesome_program` provides no option to turn ANSI escape sequences off, you can try passing `TERM=dumb` in the environment, e.g. `TERM=dumb troublesome_program`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [ANSI escape sequences/codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), so basically `ESC` [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) followed by some other characters that are used as sequences to display colors, etc.

To remove them, you can for example use [ansi2txt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ansi2txt.1.html) CLI tool, e.g.:

```
top | ansi2txt > output.txt
```

Here are also more ways to remove them: [Removing ANSI color codes from text stream](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream)

Comment: Thank you, that tool worked like a charm!